# If $\Omega$ is open and $D$ is a discrete subset of $\Omega$, is $\Omega\setminus D$ open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathcal N_\tau(x):=\{N\subseteq E:N\text{ is a }\tau\text{-neighborhood of }x\}$.

If $B\subseteq E$, then $x\in E$ is called

- *$\tau$-accumulation point of $B$* if $$\forall N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset;\tag1$$
- *$\tau$-isolated point of $B$* if $$\exists N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x)=B\cap N=\{x\}\tag2.$$

Now, in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) it is mentioned, that if $B\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$ is not $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$, then $x$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$. However, I think there is a subtle issue with this: If $x$ is not an $\tau$-isolated point of $B$, then $$\forall N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N\ne\{x\}\tag3.$$ From this, the desired claim is obvious, as long as $x\in B$. But without assuming $x\in B$, I don't see how the claim follows. We need at least to assume that $B$ is nonempty, since otherwise it is obviously wrong.

> **Question 1**: So, is the claim only correct when $x\in B$?

Builindg up on that, $D\subseteq E$ is called *$\tau$-discrete* if $$\forall x\in E:\exists N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):D\cap N\subseteq\{x\}\tag4.$$

> **Question 2**: Now, if $\Omega\in\tau$ and $D\subseteq\Omega$ is $\left.\tau\right|_\Omega$-discrete$^1$, can we show that $\Omega\setminus D\in\tau$?

---

$\left.\tau\right|_\Omega:=\{U\cap\Omega:U\in\tau\}=\{U\subseteq\Omega:U\in\tau\}$.

Comment: Id $D$ is a discrete subset of $\Omega$ then it is closed in $\Omega$. Hence $\Omega \setminus D$ is open.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do you prove that? I guess it's enough to show that if $D$ is $\tau$-discrete, then it is $\tau$-closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I did not see that statement in your linked page. What *is* mentioned and correct is that if $S$ is a subset of some space and $x \in S$ then **either** $x$ is an isolated point of $S$ **or** $x$ is a limit point ($\tau$-accumulation point as you call it) of $S$. So each set has two kinds of points.

To come to the question in the title: No. In $\Bbb R$ we can take $\Omega=\Bbb R$ or $(-1,1)$ and $D=\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \Bbb N^+\}$ which is discrete but $0$ is not an interior point of $\Omega\setminus D$.

A discrete set need not be closed, as illustrated by this example. If we define a discrete set as a set $D$ such that for all $x \in X$, there is an open neighbourhood $O_x$ such that $O_x \cap D$ has at most one point (which can be $x$ if $x \in D$ or empty), then $D$ is indeed closed and the result holds. One sees such usage in some complex analysis books e.g. Be careful with how discrete is defined. For a topologische it means the subspace topology is the discrete topology, but in analysis the meaning is sometimes the stronger one.

Comment: Regarding the first part: So, did I get you right that we need to assume $x\in B$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d If $x$ has to be an isolated point of $B$, yes of course. But like I said, the linked Wikipedia page doesn’t say what you claimed it did.

Comment: What I mean is that "If $x\in B$, then either $x$ is a $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$ or a $\tau$-isolated point of $B$". Right?

Comment: Regarding the question in the title: How is your definition from $D$ being a discrete set different from the definition of being $\tau$-discrete I gave in the question?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes that’s what I said in my first paragraph using $S$ instead of $B$ (as Wikipedia uses $S$)

Comment: @0xbadf00d The analysis definition I also gave is a condition on *all* $x$ in the space, not just all points of the set.

Comment: But my definition is on all of $x$ as well, isn't it? I said that $x\in E$ is called a $\tau$-isolated point of $B$ if $(2)$ holds ($(2)$ was broken before; fixed now). And I said that $D\subseteq E$ is called $\tau$-discrete if every $x\in D$  is a $\tau$-isolated point of $E$, i.e. $$\forall x\in D:\exists N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):E\cap N=\{x\}.$$ However, while I write this, isn't my definition nonsensical anyway? Since $E\cap N=N$, this means that every singleton set $\{x\}$ with $x\in D$ is $\tau$-open, doesn't it? That's wrong for $E=\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean topology ...

Comment: @0xbadf00d Your definition is nonsense, $\Bbb R$ doesn’t have any discrete subsets in that definition as $\Bbb R$ has no $\tau$-isolated points.

Comment: It should be correct now. How do we prove the claim then?

Comment: @0xbadf00d now your definition agrees with the analysis one I gave and implies the set is closed and so open minus closed is open etc.

Comment: Well, yes, that's my question: How do we see that it is closed?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Because if $x \notin D$ it will have a neighbourhood $N$ with $N \cap D \subseteq \{x\}$; $x$ is *not* in that intersection, so $N \cap D = \emptyset$ and so $D$ is closed (no point outside it is in its closure).

Comment: I see, you are using that $x\in\overline B$ if and only if $B\cap N\ne\emptyset$ for every neighborhood $N$ of $x$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d indeed I am.